# MFP 7.1 In few devices and network carrier the app login is not going through. But on some other devices it is working

Tags: javascript, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, ibmhttpserver

Environment:

1. Windows Server 2012 R2
2. JRE 1.8.0_101
3. IBM WAS Liberty Core 8.5.5.5
4. IBM MFP 7.1
5. IBM HTTP Server 8.5..5

We have a MFP 7.1 Server and application created with Cordova and is running on a production environment. The application working fine. Suddenly we are experiencing the following issue.
In a few devices and network carrier, the app login is not going through. Even the adapter call is not working. But on some other devices, it is working.

Also when we connect the phone to wifi or with hotspot from other devices the app works like a charm.
Have created a sample app and tried invoking an unprotected adapter it is failing in those devices where we had an issue.

We have analyzed the access.log and the trace.log
The request is arriving till the IBM HTTP Server. We haven’t found any log on the app server or plugin.

Does anyone experience the issue? Kindly suggest for any solution to solve the problem.

Comment: Is this specific to Android ? Or seen in iOS too? You mentioned the request arrives at the web server. What happens then? Does the webserver reject it? Or send it to MFP server?

Comment: Yes it occurs in both android and iOS devices. The request received in web server and transfered to the MFP server, after that we can't able to trace the request in the app server.
Note: Request not rejected by web server.

Comment: HTTP and MFP tracing in your application server ought to give the cause. Open a case with IBM to investigate further on this